# 1.You may ask: "What does it mean?" , 2."What does it mean?" you may ask. Which one is correct?

Tags: phrase-meaning, difference, colons, quotation-marks, question-marks

> 1.You may ask: "What does it mean?"
>
> 2."What does it mean?" you may ask.

● Which one is correct?

● Is the usage of the "s correct?

● What's the difference between them, if any?

● What about the use of the question mark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > 1.You may ask: "What does it mean?"
> >
> > 2."What does it mean?" you may ask.
>
> Which one is correct?

## Both

In directly quoted speech, it's more common to separate the two clauses with a comma: *You may ask, “What does it mean?”* In the first example, the colon can replace the usual comma if you mean to give the listeners a specific list of the specific things they are allowed to say. The question mark replaces the usual comma in the second one.

> Is the usage of the "s correct?

## Yes

The quotation marks enclose direct speech. You can also say *You may ask what it means.* using indirect speech. You’ll notice that the grammar changes a little to show that it's indirect speech.

There are some differences about the way Brits and Americans usually place the quotation marks with regard to other punctuation, but *both* of them usually like to put question marks like yours *inside* the quotation marks.

> What's the difference between them, if any?

The first one provides a list of questions you consider acceptable for them to ask. The second acknowledges that they themselves might have this question come to them.

> What about the use of the question mark?

As above, it's fine.